# Intro Screen Not Loading

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble getting my intro screen, defined by def game_intro(), to load properly. Whenever I run it, it just gets stuck on a blank, black screen. Before I added it, the game worked fine.

I've tried the debugger, but have not been able to successfully figure out what's wrong. I'm using the Python IDE to write the code. The problem code is below:

```py
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

scrWdt = 500 
scrHgt = 500

win = pygame.display.set_mode((scrWdt,scrHgt))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black = (0, 0, 0)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

    win.fill(white)
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Snake", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((scrWdt/2),(scrHgt/2))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)

game_intro()
```

I want to see a white screen with the word "Snake" written on it.

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you have to draw it inside `while intro` (if you assume to  animate it). OR draw it before `while intro`.

Comment: You're right! I indented from win.fill to clock.tick(100) and it appeared. Thank you so much!

Comment: zeshaykes, that's still never going to exit the loop. I assume at some point you'll want to come out of the intro screen and play the actual *game,* yes?

Comment: paxdiablo, thanks for the heads up. You're right, I do want to exit the intro. It's not in the above, but I recently added a button that exits the intro upon clicking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is simply off

```
def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                intro = False
    # ---> 
        win.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Snake", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((scrWdt/2),(scrHgt/2))
        win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)

game_intro() 
pygame.quit()
```

Just indent the rest of your game loop properly under the while loop and it works.
Also, you didn't define `white` anywhere, but for simple colors you can just use the `pygame.Color` class

In addition, I changed the breaking condition of the loop to acutally use your `intro` variable instead of `pygame.quit()`, because the latter will result in some errors with the video system (the `pygame.display.update()` is still called once after de-initialising pygame in the event loop, resulting in an error).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your comment about the breaking condition, because I kept getting the video system error you were talking about without figuring out what to change. So whenever I use `pygame.display.update()`, I shouldn't use `pygame.quit()`? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

```
intro = True
while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

I'm pretty certain that loop will run *forever,* or at least until you exit. The `pygame.event.get()` call retrieves a list of events but the only way *out* of that loop is if you get a `QUIT` one.

Hence it will never get to your code that actually does the intro.

You probably want something like (Pythonic, but *actually* pseudo-code):

```
def intro():
    displayIntroScreen()

    loopCount = 10 # For a 1-second intro
    while loopCount > 0:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        sleep(100ms)
        loopCount -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of doing a counter for the while loop. I decided to go with  furas' comment just because it's less code, but I appreciate your answer!